# Setting up a workflow for autoformatting a git repository (C)

Tags: c, repository, autoformatting

I want to set up a workflow that allows me to have a git repository with a uniform/consistent formatting. The developers (approx. 30) should be able to commit properly formatted changes to their local repository easily, independent of their operating system (either some Linux or Windows 10) and independent from their IDE. Changes shall be pushed to a Linux server which administrates the remote repository.

From my point of view there are two steps necessary to ensure that the remote repository is properly formatted:

1. Format the current state of repository according to a set of rules.
2. Format the files affected by every new commit according to these rules.

The first step can be implemented easily by running an auto-formatting tool (e.g. clang-format) on the complete repository. The implementation of the second step can be further divided into two substeps:

- 2a) Client side: Format a commit properly before pushing it to the server.
- 2b) Server side: Check if the repository will be properly formatted after the changes of the commit are applied.

The second substep (2b) can be implemented easily (simlar to step 1). However, the implementation of the first substep (2a) is more demanding and I would like to reach out to the community for tipps/tricks/ideas.

So far I've had a closer look on the Eclipse autoformatter and clang-format:

- The **Eclipse autoformatter** can only be used when Eclipse is installed, I haven't found a Eclipse autoformatter standalone application. Is it possible to run the eclipse autoformatter from the command line without a GUI?
- **clang-format** is a unix tool which I cannot install and run standalone on a windows system. I've seen there is a LLVM executable for windows but I am not sure if the installation will inflict any undesired changes to my system. Is anybody using LLVM/clang-format on windows?

Are there other auto-formatting tools for C which work on Linux and Windows 10? Is anybody successfully using python scripts for this purpose?